# Expression Tree: replace expressions like <variable> + 1 / <variable> -1 with increment / detriment operations respectively

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expression-trees

I would like to convert `() => a - 1 + b + 1` lambda to something like `() => a-- + b++` with expression tree.

I implement class `ExpressionTreeTransformer.cs` that inherits from `ExpressionVisitor.cs` and override `VisitBinary` method:

```
protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
        {
            if (!TryGetNumberValueFromExpressionNode(node.Left, out var leftNodeValue))
            {
                return base.VisitBinary(node);
            }

            if (!TryGetNumberValueFromExpressionNode(node.Right, out var rightNodeValue) || rightNodeValue != 1)
            {
                return base.VisitBinary(node);
            }

            var resultedExpression = node.NodeType switch
            {
                ExpressionType.Add => Expression.Increment(Expression.Constant(leftNodeValue)),
                ExpressionType.Subtract => Expression.Decrement(Expression.Constant(leftNodeValue)),
                _ => base.VisitBinary(node)
            };

            return resultedExpression;
        }
```

It works fine if were applied parentheses like `() => (a - 1) + (b + 1)`, but doesn't if we try () => `a - 1 + b + 1`

After some investigation i founded out that reason of that is how expression tree build nodes.
Without parentheses steps look like:

1. left(a - 1) + right(b)
2. left(result of 1 step) + right(1)

Expression nodes are processed in handlers chain:

```
_expressionHandlers = new MemberExpressionHandler();
_expressionHandlers.SetSuccessor(new ConstantExpressionHandler());
```

Variables handler:

```
public class MemberExpressionHandler : AbstractTreeExpressionHandler
    {
        public override bool Handle(Expression expressionNode, out int nodeValue)
        {
            if (expressionNode is MemberExpression memberExpression)
            {
                var constantExpression = memberExpression.Expression as ConstantExpression;
                var field = (FieldInfo)memberExpression.Member;

                if (constantExpression != null)
                {
                    var value = field.GetValue(constantExpression.Value);
                    var isNumber = int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out nodeValue);

                    if (isNumber)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (_successor != null)
                {
                    return _successor.Handle(expressionNode, out nodeValue);
                }
            }

            nodeValue = 0;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Constants handler:

```
public class ConstantExpressionHandler : AbstractTreeExpressionHandler
    {
        public override bool Handle(Expression expressionNode, out int nodeValue)
        {
            var isConstant = expressionNode is ConstantExpression;
            var isNumber = int.TryParse(((ConstantExpression)expressionNode).Value.ToString(), out nodeValue);

            if (isConstant && isNumber)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Q: I'm stuck, please share your experience how this task can be solved at right way

P.s results:

- With parentheses: () => `(Decrement(0) + Increment(1))`
- Without: `() => ((Decrement(0) +
  value(ExpressionTreeModule.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0_0).b) + 1)`

Comment: Can a single variable appear more than once? If so, using `++` or `--` will change the variable's value (whereas `+ 1` or `- 1` would not), and do you need to take that into account?

Comment: yes, it interested case. But generally i bilieve at that moment we can do with more simple impelemntation. Thanks

Comment: Note that this is deliberate - the operators are _left-associative_, and so the expression is interpreted as `((a-1)+b)+1`. This matters in cases where side effects can affect the result.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to examine the left hand side when you find a constant add or subtract of `1` and determine if you can hoist the addition/subtraction up to be an increment/decrement. Here is my sample code:

```
public class UnaryConstant1 : ExpressionVisitor {
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node) {
        if (node.Right is ConstantExpression c && c.Type.IsNumeric() && (Int32)c.Value == 1) {
            if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Add || node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Subtract) {
                if (node.Left is MemberExpression) {
                    if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Add)
                        return Expression.Increment(node.Left);
                    else
                        return Expression.Decrement(node.Left);
                }
                else if (node.Left is BinaryExpression left && (left.NodeType == ExpressionType.Add || left.NodeType == ExpressionType.Subtract)) {
                    Expression right;
                    if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Add)
                        right = Expression.Increment(left.Right);
                    else
                        right = Expression.Decrement(left.Right);

                    if (left.NodeType == ExpressionType.Add)
                        return Expression.Add(Visit(left.Left), right);
                    else
                        return Expression.Subtract(Visit(left.Left), right);
                }
            }
        }
        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }
}
```